# How to avoid call a function in redundancy

Tags: java, while-loop, udp

I made a code that allows me to exchange messages between a client and a server. I run a while loop in the class server that checks whether the client has sent a packet to the server at this point call `Checking()` function.
This `Checking()` function allows me to control some of the specific client. But there is a problem, in particular the function call is inside the while loop, so even if the client doesn't send anything to the server, the code of course always call the `Checking()` function.

How can I avoid this callback redundant?
There would be something to see if indeed the client sent a message so as to structure a condition?

Problem Example:

```
While(true)
{
    String messaggio = (new String(ricevuta.getData()).trim());
    System.out.println("Client says: " + messaggio);
    Checking();
}
```

console result:

```
Client says: hello
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
**infinite loop.**
```

What I thought:

```
if Client send something => run Checking(); function<br>
else continue;
```

Who can give me a help? Is there a method to do this on the UDP protocol?

Comment: What does ricevuta.getData() return when the client doesn't send anything? Does it return at all? - If the String has length 0, skip Checking.

Comment: I add: if(messaggio.length() > 0){ Checking();}else{continue;} but the the loop continue to infinity

Comment: When and why does it stop otherwise? Your code - as it is now - doesn't ever terminate (except when an exception is thrown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem in your code is that it allows to receive a packet from
>   client only once as far now.

And, the while loop simply prints the data in the received packet. It does not seem to be receiving a new packet.

```
while(true)
{
    String messaggio = (new String(ricevuta.getData()).trim());   
    System.out.println("Client says: " + messaggio);
    Checking();
}
```

Instead it should be like the sample below:

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket ricevuta= new DatagramPacket(receiveData,receiveData.length);
while(true)
{
    datagramSocket.receive(ricevuta);     //waits here until any packet is received
    String messaggio = (new String(ricevuta.getData()).trim());   
    System.out.println("Client says: " + messaggio);
    Checking();
}
```

So, now in every iteration of the while loop, it waits until a datagram packet is received. Only then it prints its data and calls the **checking()** function